# Cannot clone git repo from aws

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance in the cloud. I want it to be my git "server" repo.  On it,  I have  a git user and group. and I have this for directory structure:

```
/home/git/oneOfMyRepos.git/
```

I ran the "git init --bare"  and all the files are in git/oneOfMyRepos.git folder. My Amazon security group has 80,443,22 ports open.

However, on a client laptop, I try:

```
git clone  https://me.com/git/oneOfMyRepos.git
(Also tried https://me.com/oneOfMyRepos.git as well)
```

and get this:

```
fatal: repository 'https://me.com/git/oneOfMyRepos.git/' not found
```

I, of course know it's there.  I have turned off the security just for testing.

How would I go about solving this?  Is there a special port I need to open? is my clone command wrong?  And are there any logs, that are relevant here and not transaction logs?
What's up with the extra "/"  at the end of the error message?

Comment: `https://me.com` - do you have SSL set up for the EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes,  but with a self signed cert.  Git was throwing errors,  but i disabled security warnings like I said.

Comment: How did you set up the web server that exposes your git repo via https?